# LARAVEL How to transfer file from local (public) to FTP using Laravel

Tags: laravel

I wanna ask a question, anyone know how to transfer data from local / public to ftp, I'm using Storage class
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem

Here's my code

```
$file_local = Storage::disk('local')->get('public/uploads/ftp/file.pdf');
$file_ftp = Storage::disk('ftp')->put('/file.pdf', $file_local');
```

But my code is not working, when I open the file on ftp, the file is broken, then I open it with notepad, inside file, the content is 'public/uploads/ftp/file.pdf' the content I mean content should on local not what I was wrote,

Anyone know how to transfer file from local to ftp, sorry for my bad English, Thanks for your answer anyway

Answer (score 5):

To get started, you should know the details of your FTP host, FTP username, and FTP password. Once, you are ready with the details open the .env files and add the details as below:

```
    FTP_HOST=YOUR_FTP_HOST_VALUE
    FTP_USERNAME=YOUR_FTP_USERNAME_VALUE
    FTP_PASSWORD=YOUR_FTP_PASSWORD_VALUE
```

Make sure to replace the placeholders with the actual values. Next, open the config/filesystems.php file and add the ‘ftp’ configuration to the ‘disks’ array.

```
<?php
return [
    ......
    'disks' => [
        ......
        'ftp' => [
            'driver' => 'ftp',
            'host' => env('FTP_HOST'),
            'username' => env('FTP_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('FTP_PASSWORD'),
            'root' => 'DIR_PATH_TO_WHERE_IMAGE_STORE' // for example: /var/www/html/dev/images
        ],
    ],

];
```

Replace DIR_PATH_TO_WHERE_IMAGE_STORE with the actual path where you need to store images. For example, if we have folder called ‘images’ and path to this folder is /var/www/html/dev/images then this path will go as the value for ‘root’ in the above array.

For uploading files through FTP we need a form where a user can submit the image. Add the below code in your view file.

```
<form action="{{ url('PASS_ACTION_URL_HERE') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
        <input type="file" name="profile_image" id="exampleInputFile" multiple />
    </div>
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

You should replace the PASS_ACTION_URL_HERE with your actual route. As we are using a Laravel Storage to file uploading user need add Facade to the controller file as follows:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    if($request->hasFile('profile_image')) {

        //get filename with extension
        $filenamewithextension = $request->file('profile_image')->getClientOriginalName();

        //get filename without extension
        $filename = pathinfo($filenamewithextension, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

        //get file extension
        $extension = $request->file('profile_image')->getClientOriginalExtension();

        //filename to store
        $filenametostore = $filename.'_'.uniqid().'.'.$extension;

        //Upload File to external server
        Storage::disk('ftp')->put($filenametostore, fopen($request->file('profile_image'), 'r+'));

        //Store $filenametostore in the database
    }

    return redirect('images')->with('status', "Image uploaded successfully.");
}
```

‘profile_image’ is the name of our file input. We build the unique name of our file and then uploading it to an external server. Notice we have used Storage::disk(‘ftp’) method. This function would store our file to the path as defined in the configuration. A user should store the value ‘$filenametostore’ in your database.

Answer (score 0):

```
'local' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root'   => storage_path().'/app',
],
```

If you use the local disk (config/filesystems.php) you are looking in 'storage/app' not the public folder unless you have changed the default settings. So:

```
$file_local = Storage::disk('local')->get('file.pdf');
```

will look for 'Storage/App/file.pdf'

Make sure your pdf is in that folder and give this a try:

```
$file_local = Storage::disk('local')->get('file.pdf');
$file_ftp = Storage::disk('ftp')->put('file.pdf', $file_local);
```

EDIT: also, I notice in your original post second line of code you have rogue ' after $file_local ;)